# MapBox Place Picker leads to Fatal signal 6

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm following these instructions trying to implement this [Place Picker](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/places/#place-picker)

But my app crashes everytime I start it with this error: `A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL)` How can I fix it? I didn't find a solution online... Even I found GitHub issues with the same error but there was no answer. Can someone help?

Here's my code:

```
public class PlaceSelectionPluginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 5678;
    private TextView selectedLocationTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Mapbox.getInstance(this, "***myToken***");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_selection);
        selectedLocationTextView = findViewById(R.id.selected_location_info_textview);
        goToPickerActivity();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the PlacePickerOptions and startActivityForResult
     */
    private void goToPickerActivity() {
        startActivityForResult(
                new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder()
                        .accessToken("***myToken***")
                        .placeOptions(PlacePickerOptions.builder()
                                .statingCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                        .target(new LatLng(40.7544, -73.9862)).zoom(16).build())
                                .build())
                        .build(this), REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * This fires after a location is selected in the Places Plugin's PlacePickerActivity.
     * @param requestCode code that is a part of the return to this activity
     * @param resultCode code that is a part of the return to this activity
     * @param data the data that is a part of the return to this activity
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
// Show the button and set the OnClickListener()
            Button goToPickerActivityButton = findViewById(R.id.go_to_picker_button);
            goToPickerActivityButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            goToPickerActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    goToPickerActivity();
                }
            });
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
// Retrieve the information from the selected location's CarmenFeature
            CarmenFeature carmenFeature = PlacePicker.getPlace(data);

// Set the TextView text to the entire CarmenFeature. The CarmenFeature
// also be parsed through to grab and display certain information such as
// its placeName, text, or coordinates.
            if (carmenFeature != null) {
                selectedLocationTextView.setText(String.format(
                        getString(R.string.selected_place_info), carmenFeature.toJson()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.placepickertest"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'



    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v9:0.12.0'
}
```

`activity_place_selection.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_to_picker_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="go to picker activity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_location_info_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Full stacktrace:

```
2020-05-17 01:00:57.244 14576-14628/com.mycompany.mapboxpickerattempt I/oxpickerattemp: --------- beginning of crash
2020-05-17 01:00:57.265 14576-14628/com.mycompany.mapboxpickerattempt A/libc: /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r20/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::PendingJavaException" failed
2020-05-17 01:00:57.265 14576-14628/com.mycompany.mapboxpickerattempt A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 14628 (OnlineFileSourc), pid 14576 (oxpickerattempt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to require Java 8 declaration. Please add the following lines to your build.gradle (application level):

```js
compileOptions {
 sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

This is my build.gradle:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.placepicker"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v9:0.12.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have basically copy-pasted this example, which should be working: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/place-picker/

Can you please share both the application level build.gradle and the project level build.gradle, as well as your activity_place_selection.xml ?

Can you change your project level build.gradle to link mapbox:

```js
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Please de tell me how to proceed.

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace of the exception that causes the crash.

Comment: I have added the full stack trace. Please take a look at my edited question.